# convert an arraylist with audio into a .wav file (Java)

Tags: java, audio, arraylist, wav

here is my problem, someone gave me a function, which, if I understand it well, put some sound samples into an arraylist.

I'd like to create a .wav file with this audio track, and I really don't know how to do so.

Here is the code, because maybe I just don't understand it at all...

```
public class Track {



private ArrayList<Sample> sounds;
private     AudioFormat audioFormat;
            TargetDataLine targetDataLine;
public Track()
{
    this.sounds = new ArrayList <Sample>();  
}
/*** Sort the sample on the track by ascending start time ***/
public void sortTrack() {
    Collections.sort(sounds);
}

/**
 * Add a sample to the track.
 * @param fic location to the audio file.
 * @param sT set the start time in ms of the sound on the track.
 */
public void addSound(String fic, long sT) {     
    sounds.add(new Sample(fic, sT));
}

/**
 * Delete a sample to the track.
 * @param fic location to the audio file.
 * @param sT set the start time in ms of the sound on the track.
 */
public void deleteSound(String fic, long sT) {      
    int i;
    for ( i = 0; i < sounds.size() &&(
    sounds.get(i).getAudioFile().getName() == fic &&
    sounds.get(i).getStartTime() == sT); ++i) {}
    if (i < sounds.size()) sounds.remove(i);
}
```

Here is sample, imported in the code above.

```
    public Sample (String fileLocation, long sT) {

try{
    audioFile = new File(fileLocation);
    istream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(audioFile);
    format = istream.getFormat();
    startTime = sT;
    timeLenght = (audioFile.length() / (format.getFrameSize() * format.getFrameRate() )) * 1000;
}
catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
       } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   }    
    }
```

Comment: How is "Sample" defined? Please include the imports. In addition, there are a couple of obvious problems in #deleteSound(String, long). For one, String comparisons shall never use the == reference identity comparator, but always the #equals(Object) method. That is because in Java Strings are objects, not primitive values. Additionally, removing elements of a collection while manually iterating over the collection is bad practice. Use an Iterator and its #remove() operation instead.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, this is not a good Java source code simply because there are a lot of useless operation that could be automatized using some specific java tools.

Apparently, you have a huge class which represents a unique track of a specific album; the album is, off course, subdivided in distinct samples. Follows a detailed description of the methods with some tips in order to improve your code:

- sortTrack() method is used in order to sort your data according a specific ordering criteria defined in the *Sample* class. In this case you should use a specific data structure that grants to you to mantain all the data automatically sorted. I would suggest the *TreeSet* but this kind of data structure needs that the elements, which are contained in it, must implement the [Comparable interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html).
  In this way, at each insert operation, you will always have your data sorted according to the criteria that you have defined (from the code that you've posted, each sample is ordered using its start time);
- addSound() method appends the specified Sample instance in your sample's list (if you want to switch to the TreeSet, the method's implementation doesn't change);
- deleteSound() method tries to remove from your sample's list a sample which should have a specific name (fic parameter) and a specific start time (sT parameter). How does it work? It loops for until an object with the specified sample's name and start time is found or if you arrive to the end of the list (pay attention, the for loop is empty because all you need to do is to go ahead and increment the *i*, until one of the condition is false). But this kind of stuff is really awful because you should use, instead, the *remove* method which provides the ArrayList class (or in general each class which is subclass of the [Collection interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html).
  In that case you need to fix the equals() method in the Sample class in order to define when two Sample are equal.